# making a 4 stop gradient in android's xml

Tags: java, android, svg

I tried using inkscape's mesh gradient but it seems not supported in android, I need something like this:
[image]

a 4 stop gradient for android's rectangle(or any other shape, like a circle), basically 4 blends of gradient color. How do I do this in android? Or atleast by something that android supports( is illustrator's svg output taken by android)?

Comment: My SVGAndroid library should be able to render any Illustrator file you throw at it.  Though it doesn't support SVG2 mesh gradients yet..

Comment: @PaulLeBeau , it's opensource? Could you link me?

Comment: Doh! I mistyped the name of my own library! [AndroidSVG is here](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg)

Answer (score 2):

You can approximate it using multiple gradients.  This is just a quick attempt to get something close. You may be able to do better with a little extra tweaking.

```html
<svg width="250" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="1">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(149,254,149)"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(255,254,149)"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.75">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(254,151,149, 1)"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(254,151,149, 0)"/>
    </radialGradient>

    <radialGradient id="grad3" cx="1" cy="1" r="0.75">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(149,150,202, 1)"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(149,150,202, 0)"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#grad2)"/>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#grad3)"/>
</svg>
```